# fcm cordova plugin is not working on ios devices

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugin-fcm

I want to show push notifications for iOS in ionic 3 app.

I am using fcm cordova plugin.

It works for android but not for iOS.

I have uploaded push certificates on firebase for development and production.

When I send notifications from the firebase console i got no error but the message is not received.

When I send notifications via HTTP i got this error 'InvalidApnsCredential'.

Can anyone help?

Comment: "When I send notifications via HTTP" you mean that you send notification from server right?

Comment: https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/292

Comment: Also if you want people to help you please provide code how you are sending.